Many questions or one?
Imagine I have come across a long song in Hakka, and have trouble understanding it. I have been told that no distinction is made for dialects. So I come here and want to ask a question. The question is essentially one: what does this song mean and how does it say it. Of course, put that way it can be taken either as a crazy question asking for a complete translation and word-by-word analysis of the song which no-one would do, which I would expect no-one to do and which I surely don't need, or simply asking for a translation, which is not enough to me, or as something in between which can't be defined since I haven't given any research at all. So I'd expect someone maybe to post a translation and then the question to be closed and perhaps deleted. Therefore I add a translation attempt and a series of points which clarify exactly where I am in understanding the song and what I am missing. I tried that on Japanese SX, and the question was closed and deleted as a multiple question. So I had to ask piece questions, roughly one per point. But if the song is very complex, this may lead to 10-20 different question, thus flooding the site with questions which are parts of one single bigger question, which is what the song says. Besides me having to keep an eye on 10-20 different questions at the same time, which may cause me to get mixed up on what notifs I have and haven't looked at, this would really risk to fill the homepage up, making other question, which are perhaps more useful to other users, disappear at the bottom of the page. What should I do?

You can group questions that are strongly related but just use common sense and you'll be fine: 20 questions in one is not very easy to handle. Asking many questions is not a problem, if they are good questions. Make sure that they are proper so they don't get closed, because the system might block you from asking questions.

Uh-huh. What about 7 in one?

Also, consider the following situation. User X asks a question. Some time passes without an answer. Then I come in and ask 20 questions about the same song, and X's question vanishes from the homepage, buried by mine. After many days, X decides to duplicate the question to attract attention. Wouldn't that be a problem? How likely is it in your opinion?

@MickG You cannot ask that many questions anyway, there is a hard limit, 6 if I recall correctly, so you won't be able to ask 20 questions in one day. :)

Ah OK. Then it's impossible.
